# How do I remove numbers enclosed in parentheses

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I remove numbers enclosed in parentheses (1234). I want to target only numbers enclosed with parentheses (123) and not words (words)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using regular expressions to target numbers.

The regex to target numbers enclosed in parenthesis would be:

```
\((\d+)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some more words to assist in this.
Use a text editor which allows RegEx such as Notepad++.

1. Paste the text to scan
2. Search > Replace
3. Paste the RegEx expression given by Cody in Find what.
4. Leave Replace with as is (nothing)
5. Search Mode: select Regular expression by radio button, then click Replace All

Comment: Hello, I really don't think this kind of obvious answer was necessary for 8 year old 0 upvotes question.